# Making spaces between posts

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a website in which users can create posts, which they can now. However, I am making queries to the database and when I create more than one post, it just adds on to each other, I want some space in between, just like reddit or any other platform.

```
<div id="Hot" class="hotcontent">
    <?php
    echo "<div class='whole-post'>";
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT *,UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - date_created AS TimeSpent from post LEFT JOIN users on users.users_id = post.users_id order by post_id DESC;');
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($post_row = $result->fetch_array()) {
      $id = $post_row['post_id'];
      $upid = $post_row['users_id'];
      $username = $post_row['users_username'];
      $posted_by = $post_row['users_id'];
      $imagepath = $post_row['imagepath'];


      echo "<div class ='post-container-title'>";
      if ($post_row['status'] == 0) {

        $filename = "uploads/profile" . $upid . "*";
        $fileinfo = glob($filename);
        $fileext = explode(".", $fileinfo[0]);
        $fileactualext = $fileext[1];

        echo "<img src='uploads/profile" . $upid . "." . $fileactualext . "?" . mt_rand() . "' id='profileimghome'>";
        echo "<br>";
      } else {
        echo "<img src='uploads/profiledefault.jpg' id='profileimghome'>";
        echo "<br>";
      }

      echo "<p id='postedby'> Posted by </p>";


      echo "<a href='userstats.php?user=$username' id='usernameinpost'>";
      echo $post_row['users_username'];
      echo "</a>";


      echo "</div>";


      echo "<h3 id='titleinpost'>";
      echo $post_row['title'];
      echo "</h3>";

      echo "<div class ='post-container'>";
      if ($post_row['type'] == 0) {
        echo "<h5 id ='post-container-content'>";
        echo $post_row['content'] . "<br>";
        echo "</h5>";
      } else if ($post_row['type'] == 1) {
        echo "<h4 id ='post-container-content'>";
        echo $post_row['content'] . "<br>";
        echo "</h4>";
      } else if ($post_row['type'] == 2) {
        echo "<h4 id ='post-container-content'>";
        echo $post_row['content'] . "<br>";
        echo "</h4>";
      } else if ($post_row['type'] == 3) {
        echo "<h4 id ='post-container-content'>";
        $filedest = $imagepath;
        $fileinfo = glob($filedest);
        foreach ($fileinfo as $media) {
          $mime = mime_content_type($filedest);
          if (strstr($mime, "video/")) {
            echo "<video width='541' height='300' controls>";
            echo '<source src="' . $media . '" /><br />';
            echo "</video>";
          } else if (strstr($mime, "image/")) {
            echo '<img src="' . $media . '" width="543" height="300"/>';
          }
        }
        echo "</h4>";
      }
    }
    echo "</div>";

    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";

    $stmt->close();

    ?>
  </div>
```

```
 .hotcontent{
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
 
  margin:auto;
  position:relative;
  top:100px;
  width:30%;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 2s;
  animation: fadeEffect 2s;
}

.whole-post{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


.post-container-title{
border: 1px solid #ccc;
height:42px;
}


#post-container-content{
word-wrap: break-word;
}

#profileimghome{
width:40px;
}

#usernameinpost{
position: relative;
font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
left:110px;
top:-59px;
font-size: 13px;
}

#titleinpost{

word-wrap: break-word;
overflow: hidden;
max-width: 551;
}

#postedby{
position: relative;
font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
left:50px;
top:-30px;
font-size: 13px;
}

#postedingenre{
position: relative;
font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
margin:auto;
left:350px;
top:-18px;
font-size: 13px;
}

#timeforpost{
position: relative;
font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
left:150px;
top:-106px;
font-size: 13px;
}

#rating{
position:relative;
float:right;
top:-144px;
border-radius:50%;
background-color: brown;
color:white;
padding:8px;
font-size:15px;
}
```

I've tried using things like `<br>` or `<hr>` at the end but still doesn't work.
I can't figure this out, here is how it looks like:
[posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVgB3.png)

Comment: Seems like a simple top and bottom margin on `.whole-post` would do it. Also, PHP has nothing to do with this. Post the rendered HTML. We need a [mcve]

Comment: @j08691 Tried it, unfortunately didnt work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community This is literally all the code provided for that, I cannot produce a minimal example because then I would have to make connections to the database and include more PHP, since this is about users creating a post